# How to add new attribute into a json object and write it in a file?

Tags: android, json

My json structure is like,

```
{
"members": [
{
  "available": true,
  "firstName": "Jackie",
  "lastName": "Kane",
  "religion": "christianity"
},
{
  "available": true,
  "firstName": "Micke",
  "lastName": "Muhru",
  "religion": "Buddhism"
}
]
}
```

I use following code to read from file,

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quote);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int ctr;
    try {
        ctr = inputStream.read();
        while (ctr != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
            ctr = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(
                byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson g = new Gson();

    MemberList responseData = g.fromJson(jObject.toString(), MemberList .class);
```

Now I need to add another attribute `memberId` in member Object.
New Json file should look like,

```
{
"members": [
{
  "memberId": 1,
  "available": true,
  "firstName": "Jackie",
  "lastName": "Kane",
  "religion": "christianity"
},
{
  "memberId": 2,
  "available": true,
  "firstName": "Micke",
  "lastName": "Muhru",
  "religion": "Buddhism"
}
]
}
```

How could I write this into the file in Raw folder?

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable **memberId** into your class *MemberList* and after parsing JSON result, fill the memberId with your values.

```
public class Member {

    @SerializedName("memberId")
    private int memberId;

    @SerializedName("available")
    private boolean available;

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("religion")
    private String religion;

    public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }
}
```